# Gradient descent - Parameter depedancy

Tags: gradient-descent

I want to use gradient descent, and apply constraints on my variables.
For example, i want to estimate A1, A2, A3 where A1+A2+A3=1 is a constraint.

thanks!

Comment: In which language? More infos please.

Comment: Octave. I want to find 3 parameters that are correlated.
For example, i want to find optimal parameters for a problem, but the sum of said parameters is 1.